# Is there any existing commercial or free component like this?

Tags: delphi

I'm tyring to find an existing component similar to the one on the image below, from FinalBuilder 6. Don't know if it might be a custom one or if it comes with any existing package. Anyone seen anything like that?

[FinalBuilder http://img35.imageshack.us/img35/8995/finalbuildercomponent02.png](http://img35.imageshack.us/img35/8995/finalbuildercomponent02.png)

Comment: In the interest of making the question useful to other people, could you describe in words what it is about that control that you were looking for? Is it that it shows icons? That it appears to have a heading that's underlined? That the pointed-at item is drawn like a hyperlink? "Like this" isn't a useful description for anyone searching or browsing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that component is from Raize, its a Raize groupbar with the style set to Tasklist.

check out the demo from their website:
http://www.raize.com/DevTools/RzComps/DemoTrial.asp
[alt text http://img25.imageshack.us/img25/5458/raisetasklist.jpg](http://img25.imageshack.us/img25/5458/raisetasklist.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

It is a component named `TRzKeyboardGroupBar` residing in *FBMiscComponents.bpl* and seems to be made by the FinalBuilder people themselves. Although, the name implies that it is derived from `TRzGroupBar` that comes with the Raize Components *(highly recommended!)* with `Style` set to `gbsTaskList` as Logman assumes.

Answer (score 1):

[TListView with grouping](http://www.codegear.com/tw/article/38080) comes close if you are willing to write some code yourself, like the underline and click to execute. Otherwise you cloud use outlookbar/sidebar/groupbar controls like offered by [TMS Software](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/tmspack.asp?s=bar), [DevExpress](http://www.devexpress.com/products/VCL/Exbars/), [Raize](http://www.raize.com/DevTools/RzComps/Default.asp) and probably [JVCL](http://jvcl.delphi-jedi.org/).

Comment: JVCL can do this with the JvXpBar component

Answer (score 1):

you do that with VirtualTrees from SoftGems for free